Why do FIDE initial ratings include "two hypothetical opponents rated 1800"?
The FIDE regulations state:

Ra is the average rating of the player's rated opponents plus two
hypothetical opponents rated 1800. The result against these two
hypothetical opponents is considered as a draw

What is the logic behind including these two hypothetical opponents?

This change, as well as other changes to FIDE ratings, was proposed here. Page 15 contains the justification for this particular change. According to the proposal, this was intended to have two effects.
First, it decreases the variability of the initial rating. Before the change, players who started with high initial ratings tended to have their rating decline, while players who started with lower ratings tended to have their rating increase. Adding the draws tends to pull the initial rating to a middle point which FIDE hopes will more accurately indicate their level.
Second, since most unrated players would ordinarily have a strength lower than 1800, it causes initial ratings overall to be slightly higher than they otherwise would. This is intended to combat deflation from players who improve after their initial tournament.
