I played my first OTB Rapid Tournament, How do I calculate my Elo rating?
Two games were against unrated players, one rated player didn't show up and one rated player I beat had only a standard rating. So what will be my initial rating? My tournament results

According to FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 March 2024:

8.2     Determining the initial rating 'Ru' of a player.
8.2.1      If an unrated player scores zero in their first event this score is disregarded. Otherwise, their rating is calculated using all their results as in 7.1.4.
8.2.2      Ra is the average rating of the player's rated opponents plus two hypothetical opponents rated 1800. The result against these two hypothetical opponents is considered as a draw.
8.2.3      Ru = Ra + dp
Ru is rounded to the nearest whole number.
The maximum initial rating is 2200.

"dp" comes from a table earlier in the document. I more or less understand what FIDE describe and it more or less agrees with what I've seen. The "less" bit, which I haven't seen in action and which I don't altogether understand why, is the bit about adding two hypothetical draws against two 1800 players.
If we assume that the player with a standard rating but no rapid rating will have their standard rating used (which is what I've seen in blitz) then your opponents' average rating is 1713. You scored 1.5/6 = 0.25, so your fractional score p = 0.25 and looking up dp in table 8.1.1 gives -193.
So your initial rating Ru = Ra + dp = 1713 - 193 = 1520.
Note that FIDE also has a "Rating Calculator" web page where you can feed these numbers in and get the calculation done automatically. That also gives 1520 as your initial rating.
Note that if they don't count your win against the 1710 player then your initial rating goes down to 1348, i.e. too low to qualify.

See https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45396/why-do-fide-initial-ratings-include-two-hypothetical-opponents-rated-1800 for "two hypothetical draws against two 1800 players".   Last time I check the "Rating Calculator" web page" had not been updated to include the draws draws against two 1800 players.

One thing I can say is that your “performance rating” in that tournament is listed as 1492. Your official rating is “0” (unrated).
I think the standard FIDE elo calculation is the average rating of all your rated opponents.

You need to modify average oponent rating with your result, see https://ratings.fide.com/calc.phtml?page=initial
